# Can anyone help fixing my error on installing isolated-vm?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, debian, npm-install

I run into the following error installing the npm package isolated VM on Debian 11:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/isolated-vm

The log doesn't help me that much...

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/screeps/screeps-server/node_modules/isolated-vm
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild --release -j 4
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/screeps/screeps-server/node_modules/isolated-vm/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nortti/src/external_copy/serializer_nortti.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nortti/src/isolate/allocator_nortti.o
npm ERR!   AR(target) Release/obj.target/nortti.a
npm ERR!   COPY Release/nortti.a
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/external_copy/external_copy.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/external_copy/serializer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/external_copy/string.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/isolate/environment.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/isolate/executor.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/isolate/holder.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/isolate/inspector.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/isolate/platform_delegate.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/isolate/scheduler.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/isolate/stack_trace.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/isolate/three_phase_task.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/lib/thread_pool.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/lib/timer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/callback.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/context_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/evaluation.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/external_copy_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/isolate.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/isolate_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/lib_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/module_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/native_module_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/reference_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/script_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/session_handle.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm/src/module/transferable.o
npm ERR!   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/isolated_vm.node
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/home/screeps/screeps-server/node_modules/isolated-vm/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@12.22.5 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.2 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/screeps/screeps-server/node_modules/isolated-vm/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/screeps/.cache/node-gyp/12.22.5/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/screeps/.cache/node-gyp/12.22.5',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/screeps/.cache/node-gyp/12.22.5/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/screeps/screeps-server/node_modules/isolated-vm',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build', '--jobs', 4 ]
npm ERR! ../src/isolate/environment.cc:25: warning: "_GNU_SOURCE" redefined
npm ERR!    25 | #define _GNU_SOURCE
npm ERR!       |
npm ERR! <command-line>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
npm ERR! ../src/module/lib_handle.cc: In member function 'v8::Local<v8::Value> ivm::LibHandle::PrivateSymbol(v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String>)':
npm ERR! ../src/module/lib_handle.cc:58:10: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
npm ERR!    58 |  return *reinterpret_cast<Local<Value>*>(&symbol);
npm ERR!       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/module/lib_handle.cc:58:10: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbrotlidec
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbrotlienc
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcares
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnghttp2
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licui18n
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licuuc
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licudata
npm ERR! collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
npm ERR! make: *** [isolated_vm.target.mk:229: Release/obj.target/isolated_vm.node] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release" "-j" "4"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/screeps/screeps-server/node_modules/isolated-vm
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v12.22.5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/screeps/.npm/_logs/2022-05-03T11_59_47_268Z-debug-0.log
```

I can't open the log afterwards because the folder gets already deleted.

Something has to be up with the libs:
lbrotlidec, lbrotlienc

Any ideas, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the version of NodeJS that you are currently using is compatible with the version of isolated-vm that you are trying to install.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/isolated-vm#requirements

For example, I was trying to install another library and I was getting a similar error, my version of node was 16, downgraded it to 12 and no more errors.

Comment: thanks for that idea.
Can't check it anymore.
After reinstalling a lot of libs, it finally worked.
Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Jorge Armando Molano Prada How did you fix the issue? I'm running into same issue in my Amazon linux server.